# DVC experiment is restoring deleted files

Tags: dvc

I am using DVC to run experiments in my project using

```
dvc exp run
```

Now when i make changes to a file(example train.py) and run "dvc exp run" everything goes well,
but my problem is that when making changes by **deleting** a file(example train.py or an image in the data folder) as soon as i run the "dvc exp run" the file is restored.
how to stop that from happening?

This is my dvc.yaml:

```
stages:
  train:
    cmd: python train.py
    deps:
    - train.py
    metrics:
    - metrics.txt:
        cache: false
```

Comment: On your examples: 1) If you delete `train.py` with that example dvc.yaml file, `dvc run exp` will fail since the train command uses that script. 2) There's no data folder in dvc.yaml so DVC would not restore anything there. Can you clarify?

Comment: Another question for you: what version of DVC are you using? Try adding the output of `dvc version` to the OP.

Comment: And one more thinkg: does `repro` also restore deleted files? Or only `exp run`?

Comment: yeah that's the weird thing dvc repro doesn't restore the deleted files, it just fails with error "missing file". which is what i want to happen with dvc experiments too

Comment: dvc version 2.1.0

Comment: 1) no it's not failing, that's my problem it's restoring the file and running.
2)I did not mention the Data file in dvc.yaml but still if i delete an image from it when i run "dvc exp run" it will restore that image. but at the same time if i add an image no problem it works=> it's not doing checkout but something else.

Comment: https://github.com/AmineMasmoudi/mops
this is the repo i am working on, I also left a video "b.wmv" explaining the problem.

Comment: OK so I assume the data directory is tracked by some .dvc file then. Makes sense. Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234635/discussion-between-jorge-orpinel-and-masmoudi).

Answer (score 0):

*From the clarifications under the OP it seems that (both train.py and) the data files are controlled by Git.*

[DVC experiments][1] have to be based on the Git `HEAD` so `dvc exp run` may be doing `git checkout HEAD` internally, before reproducing the pipeline (dvc.yaml). Any Git-tracked files will be restored.

UPDATE: Looks like this may be a bug. Being tracked in https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/6297. Should be fixed soon!